# Difference between Request Gather Schema Statistics and OnDemand Gather Schema Statistics on Oracle EBS

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs

I'm using Oracle EBS r12, I need to understand exactly difference between Request "Gather Schema Statistics" and "OnDemand Gather Schema Statistics" on Oracle EBS.

Thanks,

Comment: Run this query `SELECT user_concurrent_program_name FROM apps.fnd_concurrent_programs_vl
   WHERE UPPER(user_concurrent_program_name) LIKE '%GATHER%'`
`

Comment: Hi Sam, Could you give me understand difference between Request "Gather Schema Statistics" and "OnDemand Gather Schema Statistics" on Oracle EBS

Comment: It's a concurrent program either run manually or scheduled just a hunch.That's why I was asking you to find out concurrent programs from that view and see the differences how the concurrent programs was defined.

Comment: 'OnDemand Gather Schema Statistics' only exists in environment managed by Oracle managed services and they insist that they need to use this one instead of the standard EBS 'Gather Schema Statistics', but couldn't give me an answer yet on the differences or their reasoning.